Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AND'
This is the error I'm getting when I trye to execute the code.(https://i.sstatic.net/Z2MVQ0mS.png)

Error message: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AND'.

StackTrace:
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString, Boolean isInternal, Boolean forDescribeParameterEncryption, Boolean shouldCacheForAlwaysEncrypted)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean isAsync, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, String method)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReader(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.InitializeReader(Enumerator enumerator)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.LargeArrayBuilder`1.AddRange(IEnumerable`1 items)
   at System.Collections.Generic.EnumerableHelpers.ToArray[T](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Linq.SystemCore_EnumerableDebugView`1.get_Items()

var AutoQAEvaluationAnswers = from ea in db.EFCAutoQAEvaluationAnswers
                              join t in db.Transcripts on ea.TranscriptId equals t.Id
                              join ef in db.EFCForms on ea.FormId equals ef.Id
                              join lr in db.LLM_Results
                                   on new { transcriptId = t.Id, useCaseId = Guid.Parse(ef.AutoQAItem), question = ef.AutoQAGenAIQuestion }
                                   equals new { transcriptId = lr.transcriptId, useCaseId = lr.useCaseId, question = lr.question }
                              where t.Id == TransId
                              select new
                              {
                                  ea.Id,
                                  ea.TranscriptId,
                                  ea.FormId,
                                  ea.AutoQAType,
                                  ea.Score,
                                  ea.FormAnswer,
                                  ea.AutoQAColour,
                                  ea.CreateBy,
                                  ea.UpdateBy,
                                  ea.UpdateDate,
                                  lr.question,
                                  lr.comments
                              };

And here are the entities:
public class EFCAutoQAEvaluationAnswers
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public int TranscriptId { get; set; }
    public int FormId { get; set; }
    public string? AutoQAType { get; set; }
    public double? Score { get; set; }
    public string? FormAnswer { get; set; }
    public string? AutoQAColour { get; set; }
    public string? CreateBy { get; set; }
    public string? UpdateBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime? UpdateDate { get; set; }
}

public partial class Transcript
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string? Filename { get; set; }
    public string? PlayFile { get; set; }
    public string? mediaId { get; set; }

    public DateTime? Processtime { get; set; }
    public DateTime? CreateTime { get; set; }

    public string? DirDate { get; set; }
    public string? Vbstatus { get; set; }
    public string? JSON { get; set; }
    public string? TextPlain { get; set; }
    public string? TextSort { get; set; }
    public string? Project { get; set; }
    public string? Link { get; set; }
    public string? Createby { get; set; }
    public string? Language { get; set; }
    public string? Channels { get; set; }
    public string? Vocabs { get; set; }

    public bool? Diarization { get; set; }

    public int? ProjectId { get; set; }
    public int? Duration { get; set; }
    public int? WordCount { get; set; }

    public string? TextVtt { get; set; }

    public bool Active { get; set; }

    public int? Cvid { get; set; }

    public string? Direction { get; set; }
    public string? DgId { get; set; }
    public string? AgentName { get; set; }

    public int? agentChannel { get; set; }

    public string? GroupId { get; set; }
    public string? AiAnalysis { get; set; }

    public Guid? PlayGuid { get; set; }

    public string? Qaform { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<CallBiTagHit> CallBiTagHits { get; } = new List<CallBiTagHit>();

    public virtual ICollection<CallBi> CallBis { get; } = new List<CallBi>();

    public virtual ICollection<CallJourney> CallJourneys { get; } = new List<CallJourney>();

    public virtual ICollection<CatRuleMatch> CatRuleMatches { get; } = new List<CatRuleMatch>();

    public virtual ICollection<KpPolicyDatum> KpPolicyData { get; } = new List<KpPolicyDatum>();

    public virtual ICollection<MedicalTerm> MedicalTerms { get; } = new List<MedicalTerm>();

    public virtual ICollection<Nemeysco> Nemeyscos { get; } = new List<Nemeysco>();

    public virtual ICollection<Nlplistener> Nlplisteners { get; } = new List<Nlplistener>();

    public virtual ICollection<Nlpresult> Nlpresults { get; } = new List<Nlpresult>();

    public virtual ICollection<Sascore> Sascores { get; } = new List<Sascore>();

    public virtual ICollection<TopicSummary> TopicSummaries { get; } = new List<TopicSummary>();

    public virtual ICollection<TransJson> TransJsons { get; } = new List<TransJson>();

    public virtual ICollection<TransMetadatum> TransMetadata { get; } = new List<TransMetadatum>();

    public virtual ICollection<Utterance> Utterances { get; } = new List<Utterance>();

    public virtual ICollection<Word> Words { get; } = new List<Word>();
}

public class EFCForms
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Guid TemplateId { get; set; }
    public string? Name { get; set; }
    public string? FieldType { get; set; }
    public string? Description { get; set; }
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    public string? QuestionType { get; set; }
    public bool? QuestionRequired { get; set; }
    public bool? QuestionNotesRequired { get; set; }
    public int? FieldOrder { get; set; }
    public string? CreateBy { get; set; }
    public string? UpdateBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime? UpdateDate { get; set; }
    public double? Weighting { get; set; }
    public bool? AutomaticFail { get; set; }
    public string? AutoQAItem { get; set; }
    public string? AutoQAGenAIQuestion { get; set; }
}

public class LLM_Results 
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public int transcriptId { get; set; }
    public Guid useCaseId { get; set; }
    public string? question {  get; set; }
    public string? answer { get; set; }
    public DateTime createDate { get; set; }
    public string? comments { get; set; }
    public string? topic { get; set; }
    public Guid? promptId { get; set; }
}

Can I know my linq query is correct or not? If it is correct - why am I getting that error?
My main purpose was to create linq query using below SQL query
select                            
    ea.Id,
    ea.TranscriptId,
    ea.FormId,
    ea.AutoQAType,
    ea.Score,
    ea.FormAnswer,
    ea.AutoQAColour,
    ea.CreateBy,
    ea.UpdateBy,
    ea.UpdateDate,
    lr.question,
    lr.comments
from
    EFCAutoQAEvaluationAnswers ea 
join 
    Transcripts t on t.Id = ea.TranscriptId
join 
    EFCForms ef on ea.FormId = ef.Id
join 
    LLM_Results lr on t.Id = lr.transcriptId 
                   and TRY_CAST(ef.AutoQAItem as uniqueidentifier) = lr.useCaseId 
                   and lr.question = ef.AutoQAGenAIQuestion
where 
    t.Id = 3759563

But when I create a linq query, I get this error:

Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AND'

SQL Server is: Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 12.0.2000.8

DON'T use EF and LINQ as if they're a way to write SQL inside C#. EF is an ORM that loads an entire graph of objects in memory, giving the impression of working with an object database. It's EF's job to generate SQL. If you have to write so many LINQ joins, you're using EF wrong. My main purpose was to create linq query using below SQL query that's a bad idea

join LLM_Results lr on t.Id = lr.transcriptId and TRY_CAST(ef.AutoQAItem as uniqueidentifier) = lr.useCaseId and lr.question = ef.AutoQAGenAIQuestion
break this join in mutltiple lines  as I can see JOIN condition was written on a single line.

As Panagiotis already mentioned, you are using EF not as it was intended. IMHO writing your own queries is indeed better, and if you want to use linq for that then use Linq2DB instead of EF. EF is way to heavy if you only want to use it to generate entities

The stack trace in the image is different from the stack trace you posted here.

Your c# should look more like await db.EFCAutoQAEvaluationAnswers.Where(ea => ea.TranscriptId == 3759563).Select( ea => new { ea.Id,     ea.TranscriptId,     ea.FormId,     ea.AutoQAType,     ea.Score,     ea.FormAnswer,     ea.AutoQAColour,     ea.CreateBy,     ea.UpdateBy,     ea.UpdateDate,     ea.SomethingHereThatNavigatesToLLMResults.Question,     ea.SomethingHereThatNavigatesToLLMResults.comments }).ToListAsync()

First thing to do when getting such an error is to look at the generated SQL. What does it look like and where is the syntax error?

In original LINQ query, the issue occurred because use ef.AutoQAItem inside the LINQ query and attempting to parse it into a Guid before performing the join. This leads to an invalid SQL.
Try This
var form = await db.EFCForms
                        .Where(ef => ef.AutoQAItem != null)  
                        .FirstOrDefaultAsync();


var useCaseId = Guid.Empty;
if (form != null)
{
    Guid.TryParse(form.AutoQAItem, out useCaseId);
}

var AutoQAEvaluationAnswers = from ea in db.EFCAutoQAEvaluationAnswers
                              join t in db.Transcript on ea.TranscriptId equals t.Id
                              join ef in db.EFCForms on ea.FormId equals ef.Id
                              join lr in db.LLM_Results
                                  on new { transcriptId = t.Id, useCaseId = useCaseId, question = ef.AutoQAGenAIQuestion }
                                  equals new { transcriptId = lr.transcriptId, useCaseId = lr.useCaseId, question = lr.question } into lrJoin
                              from lr in lrJoin.DefaultIfEmpty()
                              where t.Id == transId
                              select new
                              {
                                  ea.Id,
                                  ea.TranscriptId,
                                  ea.FormId,
                                  ea.AutoQAType,
                                  ea.Score,
                                  ea.FormAnswer,
                                  ea.AutoQAColour,
                                  ea.CreateBy,
                                  ea.UpdateBy,
                                  ea.UpdateDate,
                                  lr.question,
                                  lr.comments
                              };


the issue is that TRY_CAST function with ON Clause. SQL Server does not allow TRY_CAST function directly in ON Clause. Use as below:
where  TRY_CAST(ef.AutoQAItem as uniqueidentifier) = lr.useCaseId

